# position fixed not changing with after changing orientation on phone on Android default browser

Tags: css, mobile, viewport

When I change the orientation from portrait to landscape on the phone my `.site-header` width is remaining the same width as it was on portrait, whereas I would like it to fit the new browser width....

This is only happening in Androids Internet browser.

```
.site-header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index:9999999;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Im using this for my viewport...

```
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Thank you

Comment: have you checked your .site-header is not inside a fixed width container right?

Comment: yes and theres nothing there giving it a fixed width, Im adding an update now to the post, it turns out this is only happening in Androids default browser , perhaps thatll it make it more difficult to solve

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to take the full width of the device (not the full width of the container) use `width:100vw;` instead of 100%.

This will make it take the viewport width whether it's portrait or landscape.

**Note** that viewport unit is not compatible with older browsers, check this link http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: The viewport unit is not really compatible with all browsers nearly 60% ==> http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer? I have the same issue on ipad in the Safari browser. On rotate from portrait to landscape, any non-fixed position items with 100% width would expand to fill the screen, but the fixed position items with 100% width would stay at a width of 768px.

I only had this issue when using the youtube api, but I'm not sure if it occurred because of a conflict, or if it was happening just because that api is such a resource hog. Sometimes, but not always, after a few seconds the page would finally re-adjust the widths as I scrolled.

I put in a bit of a hack to fix it, so please let me know if you have found something better:

```
$(function() {//on page load
  window.onorientationchange = function(){//on device rotate
    $(".myfixeddivs").width($(window).width());//manually adjust widths
  }//end on device rotate
});//end on page load
```